# Magento does not allow uploading avatar image having width larger than 2000px

Tags: magento, upload, width, image-uploading

While uploading avatar image in frontend inmagento 1.9.1.0 it returns me the below error. Images having width less than 2000px can be uploaded successfully. At backend it does allow images even larger than 2000px.
"Maximum allowed image width for 'IMG_20160610_195019258.jpg'
 is 2000 px."

[image]

Comment: Did you created or installed any module for uploading avatar image?

Comment: Have you made any changes to get functionality for uploading avatar image?

Comment: No but granada theme is in use.

Comment: Are you sure? I checked demo of this theme and could not find avatar upload feature. Please recheck by which module you have got this functionality, so that I can help you.

Comment: We need to enable avatar option for frontend registration.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this extension:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/avatar.html

This extension is free and has sufficient users' reviews.